# How to create mac vps (virtual private server) and access it via browser

Tags: xcode, macos, cloud, vps

How to create mac vps (virtual private server) and log in to it via browser, I want to be able to create environment like http://www.macincloud.com/, i have os x server but not sure how to set it up so that it can be accessed via browser, reason i'm trying to do this is to be able to use xcode from windows machine over internet.

any help is much appreciate it

Comment: I'm assuming you have a mac, correct?

Comment: Yes ! i have a mac and i also have osx server app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how OSX Server works, but I believe what you want to do can be completed using a VNC.

Here is a quick tutorial I found on youtube on how to create a VNC on your mac computer so that you can control it from another computer by logging into the VNC server.

You will not be able to use your browser to log in, so you will need to download a 3rd party application (tightVNC is mentioned in the video) to access your mac remotely.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13vIi37TkCg

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you requirement is something that you want to access through browser means you can do it easily using Apache(web server) which is preinstalled in mac and host something there with plain html page or with simple php which is also preinstalled in mac.